# Django restframework serializer response custom message

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, response, message

I'm trying to override the response message(return data) of the serializer. Below is my sample code.

***models.py***

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.charField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.charField()
```

***serializer.py***

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'email', 'phone')

    def validate(self, data):
        '''
            Some validation here
        '''
        return data
```

***views.py***

```
from rest_framework import generics

class MyModelList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
```

Here, when I try to post the data, the serializer return the response in the json format like this

```
{
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'myname',
    'email': 'mayname@example.com',
    'phone': 8569874587,
}
```

But I want to return the custom json response like this if the post is success.

```
{
    'success' : 'data posted successfully',
}
```

Guys how can I override this for the custom message, please help me for this, it will be very great-full, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overwrite the create method of `ListCreateAPIView`

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(
             {"Success": "Data posted successfully"},
             status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
             headers=headers)
```